# How i can Upload large size files

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload

I have issue  !  I've  read somewhere that the maximum value which we may transfer  2GB by IIS 6 but i need to create  application using C# which could be able to upload files with size over than 150mb and to be able to upload files to many users at the same time.Can anyone tell or show an example how to works file exchange site

Comment: This is a common problem:
http://xkcd.com/949/

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a link where you read about a 2GB restriction?

I'm pretty sure it's not the case if you use `transferMode="Streamed"` for your WCF binding. Also, remember to set both `httpRuntime maxRequestLength` and `binding`'s `maxReceivedMessageSize` and `maxBufferSize` to appropriate values.

In regards to example, it depends on the type of web service you want to use. If it's a RESTful web service, you just need to define a method similar to the following:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/fileUpload/?userId={userId}" )]
public void UploadFile( int userId, Stream fileStream)
{
    // Here you read the file from fileStream
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/08/28/file-transfer-with-wcp/) on streamed file transfer with WCF. It shows how to create a streaming WCF service for file upload/download from scratch. Size should not matter, for you basically pass a stream in a message, and you can set max message size.